# How can I ask for facebook permissions after they have logged in to my site/app?

Tags: java, facebook, http, http-get

I currently have the my application asking for extended permissions to publish to the user's wall at login. Is there someway to make the application ask for these extended permissions not at login but later when they first want to post something to their wall?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a hierarchical workflow where you ask for current_permissions and extend them by more extended permissions before calling the FB.ui() method. For this you might have a look the following component that can manage this for you: http://www.facebook.com/pages/Helper-Component-Community/222933037808340?sk=app_412923142052609

here an example of creating such a workflow:

```
var publishStreamDummy = function() {

    // user granted the permission to stream publish ... so we call an FB.ui dialog
    FB.ui({
        yourUiParams          
        },      
        function(response) {
          if(typeof response['post_id'] != 'undefined')
              // posted
          else
              // post failed
        }
    );
} 
// the deny-callback
var publishStreamDenied = function() {
    // the user denied the publish 
}

    // check permission and save access token via ajax
    fbHelper.loginAndSave('publish_stream', 'general', 
                            {   func : publishStreamDummy, 
                                params : null,
                                cufa : true
                            } ,
                            {   func : publishStreamDenied, 
                                params : null,
                                cufa : true
                            } 
                        );
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you can't.

When you ask for some permissions you define the "scope" of your app. So user can be aware of what your app will be able to do.

If you try to remove the ability to post on their wall and then add it. you won't be able to do it since the token your first got only has permission for what your first ask for.

Comment: That’s nonsense, you can always ask for more permissions by doing another call to FB.login (or the server-side way). If the user has already connected to your app, they will be asked only for the permissions they haven’t granted yet. That call will return an access token, and with that you can do whatever the newly granted permissions (plus the old ones) allow for.

Comment: And btw., even in the FB docs they recommend only asking for the permissions you need at that moment, and ask for more permissions later on if you need them then. And it’ll most likely make more sense to the user, if they are only asked for permissions that are somehow connected to the action they’re currently undertaking within your app, instead of being asked for a whole lot of permissions „just in case”.

Comment: right. but you will have to get a new token. why do you want to ask twice for permissions and make the user re-authenticate with facebook?

Comment: i disagree. if you want your facebook app to be scalable you should foresee the scope  and therefore only ask one time only. but anyways maybe i wasnt specific enough

Comment: What does this have to do with scalability? (And what exactly do you mean by that in the context of a facebook app?)